# Can I use custom field types for custom category fields?

Tags: categories, custom-fields

I have just gone to add some custom fields to my category group when I was shocked to find that there was no way to define a rich text field. There are only several basic field types.

Is there a plugin which adds a richer selection of field types for categories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/editor) allows a WYSIWYG for the *category description field* only. Not sure if that will be enough for your needs, but it might be worth looking into.

You can see a picture of what that will look like:

[image: Editor in categories]

Comment: Does Editor allow you to upload and insert HTML5 videos?

Comment: Lea it sure appears that way! I've added an image to this answer (should appear soon.)

Comment: @Natetronn do you know if it is possible to create custom buttons for Editor? I sent the developers an email 2 days ago but haven't heard from them yet. thanks

Comment: The docs are a little bit thin though, looks like it's possible: http://www.devdemon.com/docs/editor/create_button.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid your answer is no.

EE does not make it's custom field types available outside of the Channels functionality and it would be a nice feature to have in other parts of the system such as for Members or some addons like ones that add form functionality.

This is why you see several addons such as Profile:Edit and Zoo Visitor actually create a relationship between the default Member functionality and the Channels, so that you can have more control over managing your users custom fields with the benefits of EE's custom field types.

I have not seen any similar solution for Categories.

Some unsatisfying options to consider:

- Add HTML directly to your Category fields.  They may not have a Wysiwyg but they will accept HTML.
- Experiment with the "Default Text Formatting" setting which allows you to modify the output of the category fields with a plugin that you have installed
- Consider creating a channel and using a relationship field instead

Like I said, all unsatisfying!

Comment: Ohhh, the same problem for user profiles also... How can you create a relationship field between a channel and a category?

Comment: Is it feasible to create a channel specifically for category content and then automatically associate content with respective categories using `url_title`?

Comment: Lea, yes it is possible. The channel_short_name and the category_url_title just need to be identical. How you specifically code the relationship will depend on what you're doing exactly. Since this is a new question, I'd suggest a new post with more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

A number of people have decided to abandon native EE categories and replace it with a combination of [Pixel & Tonic's Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) and channel entries.

Playa is an add-on that allows you to create complex (or simple) relationships between entries.

The idea with that is:

- Forget about using EE categories
- Create a 'Categories' channel where each entry represents a category
- Add whatever custom fields you require to the 'Categories' channel
- In the channel(s) that you want to use categories on, create a Playa custom field which references the entries in your 'Categories' channel.

**Edit:**
Mark Croxton has released [Tax Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tax-playa) which lets you use this technique alongside Taxonomy to *really* create a category replacement.